# Custom scrollbar on specific divs

Tags: jquery, scrollbars

I need a way to scroll two separate "divs" (actually `<nav>` and `<section>`, but lets call them div's for simplicity) individually.

One is a vertical nav on the left, the other is a section. Whenever either overflows I want a custom scrollbar to appear inside the div, and when they are scrolled the other one should remain unchanged.

My guess is I have to do this with jQuery? All I got sofar is `overflow: hidden;` in `<body>` to hide the standard scrollbars. What's the easiest way to add the custom scrollbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

> jScrollPane is a cross-browser jQuery plugin by Kelvin Luck which converts a browser's default scrollbars (on elements with a relevant overflow property) into an HTML structure which can be easily skinned with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice jquery plugin:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm